# Meta logo is not properly clickable?

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, logo, opera

The logo displayed at the top of each SE site is designed to link to the respective site's homepage. This works fine on most SE sites, *except* Meta SE.

For some reason, the logo is only clickable on its very left edge, as demonstrated below.

[image: clickable on left edge only]

I'm using Opera stable 37.0.2178.43.

Using `Inspect Element`, this is what I see...

[image: inspect element of logo]

Comment: I tried in the exact same version of Opera and the entire logo is clickable. Have you tried right clicking on the unclickable area and choosing Inspect Element to see what it thinks is there blocking the link?

Comment: @animuson Added an image of what I see using `Inspect Element`.

Comment: @scriptHero That's exactly what it should look like. The orange represents the margin which pushes it to the correct location, and the blue is the actual element. I've no idea why your browser isn't letting you click on it, but it seems specific to your instance only.

Comment: That was my troubleshooting advice. Not being clickable would generally mean there was another element on top of it which was blocking the cursor's access to it, but inspecting the element would have selected the top-layer element and not the link. If there's really nothing else there, then Opera just isn't rendering it properly for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been fixed since I originally posted this question.

Comment: Oded seems to have found the cause and fixed it up yesterday.